# How to get id values after saving an ActiveRecord model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model (I'm on rails 2.3.8) called user and I'm saving it as

```
user = User.new
user.name = "user name"
user.save!
```

what I want to do is get the generated user id after creating the user. But currently it returns true/ false value upon saving

How can I get the saved user id?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just call `user.id` after you've saved.

Answer (score 2):

For people who looking for **on create** in model, below is the way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
...  
  after_create :do_something

  def self.do_something
   user_id = id #this will have last created id
   # use this according to your needs
  end
...
end
```

Answer (score -7):

the way I did it was

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
...  
  id = nil
  after_save {id = self.id}
...
end
```

and then the local variable id is available throughout the model

Comment: @Chowlett nailed it above. Just reference `user.id` after the save.